# Decomposition of the polynomials with positive integer coefficients and splitting on the rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $P \in \mathbb{N}[X]$ be a polynomial, splitting on $\mathbb{Q}$ and with $P(0)=1$.

*Question*: Are there $k_1,  \dots , k_d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(X) = \prod_i (k_iX+1)$ ?

Comment: "splitting" = "splitting into linear factors" ?

Comment: @lhf: Yes, with rational roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem):

> Every rational root of $P$ is of the form $p/q$ with $p,q$ coprime integers, $p$ dividing $P(0)$ and $q$ dividing the leading coefficient of $P$.

This implies that $p=\pm1$.

Now, $P$ cannot have positive roots since all its coefficients are nonnegative.

Therefore, $p=-1$ and the root $-1/q$ gives the factor $qX+1$.

Comment: Ok. If all the coefficients are nonnegative and $\alpha \ge 0$, then $P(\alpha) \ge 1$, so that there is no positive root.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux, exactly.